# Dynamically create a new DOM for every new object in JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am a newbie in Javascript and trying to play with API. I have a json file, it's a daily menu of a restaurant.

```
{
"meta": {
"generated_timestamp": 1489170614,
"requested_timestamp": 1489096800,
"ref_url": "http://www.sodexo.fi/sibat",
"ref_title": "Sibelius-Akatemia T-talo"
},
"courses": [
{
"title_fi": "Juustoista broilerpataa",
"title_en": "Cheesy chicken stew",
"category": "Campus-konsepti",
"properties": "G, L",
"desc_fi": "",
"desc_en": "",
"desc_se": ""
},
{
"title_fi": "Pinaattiohukaisia, puolukkasurvosta ja kermaviilikastiketta",
"title_en": "Spinach pancakes with lingonberry and sour cream sauce",
"category": "Vegetarian",
"properties": "L",
"desc_fi": "",
"desc_en": "",
"desc_se": ""
},
{
"title_fi": "Tomaattikeittoa",
"title_en": "Tomato soup",
"category": "Soup",
"properties": "G, L",
"desc_fi": "",
"desc_en": "",
"desc_se": ""
},
{
"title_fi": "Mango-valkosuklaamousse",
"title_en": "Mango and whitechocolate mousse",
"category": "Sweet",
"desc_fi": "",
"desc_en": "",
"desc_se": ""
}
]
}
```

And I am trying to display all of the meals dynamically with the following format:

```
<h2>ref_title</h2>
<p>title_fi(title_en)</p>
<p>category</p>
<p>desc_fi(desc_en)</p>
```

Could anyone help me with that. I was looking at append() but I am still so confused. Thank you !

Comment: So... do you know about `document.createElement()` and `.textContent`?

Comment: Creating a DOM for every object would be a different thing...

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that, could it be "create a new HTML for every object" ?

Answer (score 1):

So, I wasn't quite sure what ref_title was because it wasn't inside the array, so I substituted title_fi instead:

The following code will **loop** through all courses and print relevant information to

```
for (var i = 0, len = menu.courses.length; i < len; i++) {      
    $(".menu").append("<h2>" + menu.courses[i].title_fi + "</h2>"
                    + "<p>" + menu.courses[i].title_en + "</p>"
                    + "<p>" + menu.courses[i].category + "</p>"
                    + "<p>" + menu.courses[i].desc_en + "(" + menu.courses[i].desc_fi + ")</p>");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">

</div>
```

Here's a handy fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/vxetbnn9/1/

Comment: If you could mark it as answer, that would help me a lot.